# Google Script `SlidesApp.openById` or `SlidesApp.openByUrl` returning empty object `{}`

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Im developing an automated google slide decks generator from an API.

Currently I cant seem to retrieve any values from
`var slides = SlidesApp.openById("ID");` or `SlidesApp.openByUrl("URL")`.

It is only returning `{}` output. How do I export the presentation object correctly?

Comment: Although I'm not sure your actual situation, if you had said about the log from `console.log(SlidesApp.openById(id))` that `id` is the valid value. In this case, `{}` is shown at the log. If you want to check whether the object of Presentation is returned, how about checking `console.log(SlidesApp.openById(id).toString())`? In this case, `Presentation` is seen at the log. But I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `the presentation object` in your question. So can you provide the detail goal you expect and also provide the detail flow for retrieving `{}` in your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike strangely despite executing `console.log(SlidesApp.openById(id))` and returning `{}`. The object is correctly retrieved. Is there a way to `console.log` visibly? 

I found out that it was working because I managed to perform changed on its Slide's Shape object and saw the change was made despite Presentation object returning `{}`

Comment: What do you mean by "exporting the presentation object"? What do you want to do with it? See the text content? Insert the slides into another presentation? Export the file to another format?